Problem installing pyLucene 9.10.0 on windows 11
I have been trying to install the pyLucene library on windows 11. This is the first time i try to install this library. I had a difficult time building and setting up the environment. Finally I managed to successfully build the make file without errors. But then I get a message in the command prompt :
...collections.py --module python/ICUNormalizer2Filter.py --module python/ICUFoldingFilter.py --module python/ICUTransformFilter.py --resources lucene-java-9.10.0/lucene/analysis/icu/src/resources --files 16 --build

make: *** [Makefile:290: compile] Error 2

The line that the error refers to is :
compile: jars resources
    $(GENERATE) --build $(DEBUG_OPT)`

The modifications I made in the Makefile are :
# Windows   (Win32, Python 2.7, Java 1.6, ant 1.8.1, Java not on PATH)
PREFIX_PYTHON = /cygdrive/c/Users/mysmu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/python.exe
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc --shared --find-jvm-dll client
NUM_FILES=16

I don't know how to resolve the issue and I could not find any help online. Could you please help me install pyLucene in my system? At this point any bit of help would be gratefull!

I was getting the same error when I tried in the past to download pylucene on Windows.
What I did was to switch to a Linux virtual machine, Ubuntu 22.04, specifically. In Linux, I managed to install it in three different VMs quickly, and without any problems.
There is another solution, using a docker image of pylucene. Here is the link to the docker images of different versions of pylucene.
